# Recursively delete empty folders until not empty directory is found up the dir-tree

Tags: c#, recursion

I have an architecture for a large number of images building the images folders based on a GUID:

> C:\AdPictures\7e\42\1a\dc-7\3b\7-\4e\c2-9\ee\f-\f2\4c\7d\4a\32\14\

I need to make a recursive delete until a folder is not empty from folder "14" up to the directory "7e" ("AdPictures" folder needs to remain because it's the root).

I found:

```
Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
```

but when used it deletes everything.

How can i implement a method that deletes all empty directories starting from the bottom and stopping after a non-empty directory up the tree is found?

My solution should use recursion.

Comment: you are deleting the parent directory that contains all your other directories get into them check'em then delete

Comment: is the directory structure linear as shown or will it branch out?

Comment: so dc-7 will branch maybe two more children but you don't want to start there you want to start at 14 - gotcha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the recursive method.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
DeleteFolderIfEmpty(dir);


public void DeleteFolderIfEmpty(DirectoryInfo dir){
   if(dir.EnumerateFiles().Any() || dir.EnumerateDirectories().Any())
        return;
   DirectoryInfo parent = dir.Parent;
   dir.Delete();

   // Climb up to the parent
   DeleteFolderIfEmpty(parent);
}
```

Preventing deletion of Root

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
DeleteFolderIfEmpty(dir);


public void DeleteFolderIfEmpty(DirectoryInfo dir){
   if(dir.EnumerateFiles().Any() || dir.EnumerateDirectories().Any())
        return;

   if(dir.FullName == @"c:\folder\root")
        return;

   DirectoryInfo parent = dir.Parent;
   dir.Delete();

   // Climb up to the parent
   DeleteFolderIfEmpty(parent);
}
```

Comment: It will stop if Root is not empty, you want to retain Root even if it is empty?

Comment: Hi, I have just tested and it's working fine! It seems that the bounty has expired, do you know how can I give it to you anyway?

Answer (score 1):

[getdirectories msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

basic recursion model for this.

```
void checkDIR(string Path)
{
//Path will equal AddImage right? 
   foreach(string childpath in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
         //so here we are calling checkpaths for 7E GUID Directory Structure
         checkpaths(childpath);

    }
}

void checkpaths(string Path)
{



   foreach(string childpath in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {  //here we dig deeper
         checkpaths(childpaths);//recursion


    }
    //the first recursion to get here will be the deepest directory
   //we are now in '14'

   if(there are any files)
   {do what you want}
   else
   {
    do what you need
   }

}
```

you may need some flags or other counters and variables to test and track things but this is what you are looking for. as long as you call delete in the `checkpaths` `addimage` will not be deleted

Comment: Hi thanks, but I want to go from the end of the path to the root, and stop in the way if I found a non empty folder

Comment: @Patrick do you know the  names of the deepest directories before hand? while this recusive structure starts from the root directory the checkpaths for a/b/c won't end until a/b/c/d is done so this is already kind-a set up like that. because it will check d before c it all depends on how you set up the file checking part of the code before and after the foreach loop in checkpaths. its hard for me to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dir = "a/b/c/d";
white (true) {
    If (Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir).Any() || 
        Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir).Any()) break;

    Directory.Delete(dir);

    dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(dir);
 }
```

If i understand corectly your question, tren this will delete all folder úntil find one not empty.

**EDIT**

Simply change to this:

```
var dir = "a/b/c/d";
white (!Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir).Any() && 
       !Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir).Any()) {
    Directory.Delete(dir);

    dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(dir);
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes that's correct but I would like to avoid a while(true) function...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DirectoryInfo.Delete()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adtekwst%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [DirectoryInfo.Parent property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). A possible solution using recursion could look like this:

```
private void deleteEmptyDirectories(String path)
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    // if directory is empty
    if (di.GetFiles().Count() == 0 && di.GetDirectories().Count() == 0)
    {
        di.Delete(); // it
        // and go one up
        deleteEmptyDirectories(di.Parent.FullName);
    }
    // else stop (recursion) here
}
```

The function can be used like this:

```
var start = @"c:\path\to\sub\directory\";
deleteEmptyDirectories(start);
```

Comment: I was going to say something about the checkDirectory call ;)

Comment: @RadioSpace Fixed it - i changed the name to `deleteEmptyDirectories` just before pasting the code and forgot the recursive call ;-)

Comment: @RadioSpace Read the documentation at MSDN and try it out. It is possible. I think internally the .NET Framework goes a directory up and then deletes the specified directory.

Comment: You can use `!bla.Any()` rather than `bla.Count() == 0`

Comment: well I guess the Array returned from `GetDirectories()` would not change as the directory structure does. but the docs says DirectoryInfo.Delete deletes the DirectoryInfo if it is empty. [delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adtekwst(v=vs.110).aspx) does this delete the actual directory because it only implies so

Comment: @RadioSpace you are probably right: DirectoryInfo is not visiting (going into) the directory at all, but just reading the content, so deleting should not be a problem.

Comment: okay I checked that DirectoryInfo.delete actually deletes the directory. good ol msdn being somewhat vague though its always in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @pasty Hi thanks, but your function never calls deleteEmptyDirectories because di.GetDirectories is always 0, has you are at the end of the path. What I need is to go up in the path and delete the current directory if it's emty, and going up until it's not

Comment: @Patrick i now understood your problem - you are starting from the bottom. I changed my solution. Now it should do what you want to achieve - if the sub-directory is empty deletes it, and goes one up, until a non-empty is found.

Comment: @pasty even changing your condition to di.GetFiles().Count() == 0 && di.GetDirectories().Count() == 0 to garranty that it only deletes if it's empty, it's stange because in execution it only deletes the first one but in debug mode, step by step, it's working fine...

Comment: As you are executing the application you are not into the directory right (in windows explorer or in a command prompt)? IMO the condition should be `||`.

Comment: I check if it's deleted in Windows Explorer if I understand your question correctly. IMO it's && because I had a situation when the folder was not empty and it was deleted...

Comment: You are probably right - it should be `&&`. What i meant with my question was - while the application is started are you in the last directory in you tree, because you should not be (the directory can not be deleted if it is in use). For example: your directory tree is `c:\d1\d2\d3\d4`. You navigate to `d4` to see the directory content either with windows explorer or using a command prompt `c:\>cd c:\d1\d2\d3\d4\*enter*`.

Comment: Ok let my try. BTW I found another issue to my problem, is that it deletes the base folder (C:\AdPictures\) where all the others are stored, one more problem for my basket to solve, it need to stop before that :) Thanks.

Comment: Thi scould be easily done by adding a second parameter to the function for example: `string stopAtDirectory` and then check if current directory name equals the specified string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code sample.
It is intended for deletion of all empty subfolders of a specified parent folder and contains two methods:

1. The first method `RemoveEmptyFolders` simply lists subfolders of a
   specified folder and calls the second method for each of them.
2. The second one `RemoveEmptySubFolders` is called
   recursively to check whether particular subfolder's tree is empty
   and deletes it if so.

The code:

```
private void RemoveEmptyFolders(string path)
{
    foreach (string subFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        RemoveEmptySubFolders(subFolder);
}

private bool RemoveEmptySubFolders(string path)
{
    bool isEmpty = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Aggregate(true, (current, subFolder) => current & RemoveEmptySubFolders(subFolder))
        && Directory.GetFiles(path).Length == 0;
    if (isEmpty)
        Directory.Delete(path);
    return isEmpty;
}
```

Usage:

```
RemoveEmptyFolders(@"C:\AdPictures");
```

But if you need to delete a particular subtree that ends with '14', you don't need a recursion, all other answers meet your needs.

Comment: Bad Naming Convention, C# does not recommend usage of method names with smaller letter, creating methods with different logic with different case method names is bad design.

Comment: Hi, I have tested but it's not working because the starting path must be C:\AdPictures\7e\42\1a\dc-7\3b\7-\4e\c2-9\ee\f-\f2\4c\7d\4a\32\14\ and it's going up to C:\AdPictures\ where it as to stop